# Docker WORKDIR confusion

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I’m a beginner with Docker and I have a really basic Dockerfile for practicing purposes.

```
FROM debian:latest
WORKDIR /init
COPY hello_world.sh .
RUN hello_world.sh
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

After I try to build the image, I get this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM debian:latest
 ---> ee11c54e6bb7
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /init
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 605ee1ff67e9
Step 3/5 : COPY hello_world.sh .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f544ee4e93b8
Step 4/5 : RUN hello_world.sh
 ---> Running in c4cbd6389bc2
/bin/sh: 1: hello_world.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c hello_world.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

If I modify the RUN directive and set an absolute path **/init/hello_world.sh**, it works well. Based on the description, the above Dockerfile should work.

From the Dockerfile reference:

```
The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.
```

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `RUN ./hello_world.sh`. The fact that *WORKDIR* used by RUN detective, doesn't mean that in automatically in the PATH. This is still only the **working directory** where a process is executed.

Comment: Oh my...how did I missed this? You are absolutely right. Thanks!